# How to myList.addAll(newList) will put new items of newList to top & push the existing items of myList to the bottom?

Tags: java

Does any one know a very simple method to do that. Ex:

```
List<String[]> myList=new ArrayList<String[]>();
myList.add(s1);
myList.add(s2);

List<String[]> newList=new ArrayList<String[]>();
newList.add(n1);
newList.add(n2);

myList.addAll(newList);
```

will print out:

```
s1
s2
n1
n2
```

Can we make a method like `addAllToTop` so that

`myList.addAllToTop(newList);` will print out:

```
n1
n2
s1
s2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the [overload of `addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) which takes the index at which to insert the items:

```
myList.addAll(0, newList);
```

No need for a new method at all.

Comment: work perfectly, this is very rare knowledge, thank u very much

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the adding order like below

```
newList.addAllToTop(myList);
```

Or use [addAll(int index, Collection c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28int,%20java.util.Collection%29) with index from `ArrayList` api

Comment: how to  accumulated the List